# Add non-modular dependancy in modular project

Tags: java, maven, module, dependencies

I am pretty new to the system of the modular project.
For the context, I began a JavaFX project in version 17 and I have now a `module-info.java` file that I never heard before.
With more informations I begin to understand how it works. But I have an issue.

In my project I use Maven and I add this dependency :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    <version>24.0.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I want to use the `@NotNull`, `@Nullable` etc... annotations in my project. But when I try to use it I have this error when I run :

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NotNull
  location: class be.machigan.dvdindexer.services.DVDFolder
```

So I was thinking of add it to the `module-info.java` file like this :

```java
module DVDIndexer {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires com.google.gson;
    requires org.jetbrains.annotations; // <- here

    opens be.machigan.dvdindexer to javafx.fxml, com.google.gson;
    opens be.machigan.dvdindexer.services to com.google.gson;
    exports be.machigan.dvdindexer;
    exports be.machigan.dvdindexer.controllers;
    opens be.machigan.dvdindexer.controllers to javafx.fxml;
}
```

But when I run it, I have this error :

```
java: module not found: org.jetbrains.annotations
```

And whith that error the annotations isn't recognized by the IDE (like the other situation above).

I have search on Internett and I have learn that the error can occurs because of the dependency doesn't have a `module-info.class` file. But I search on the Github of the dependency and there is a `module-info.java`. [Here](https://github.com/JetBrains/java-annotations/blob/master/module-info/src/main/java/module-info.java).

And even that, for the futur I don't know how to add a dependency that doesn't have a `module-info.java`.

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: Note when you have an annotation-only dependency, where those annotations only have meaning at compile-time, you should prefer `requires static` over just `requires`. As for dependencies that don't have a module-info descriptor, they can still be declared in a requires directive. These modules are known as "automatic" modules, and their names and versions are determined using [the algorithm described here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html#of(java.nio.file.Path...)). However, automatic modules cannot be used with the `jlink` tool.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for the precisions (if I use annotation I'll use this static keyworkd) !
For the second commentary, it's normal that I can't have access to these annotations in the code ? So it means that I can't use it ?

Comment: To clarify, you _are_ using an annotation-only dependency. And you know it only has meaning at compile-time because you used `<scope>compile</scope>` in you POM file. Plus, [these annotations](https://github.com/JetBrains/java-annotations/blob/master/common/src/main/java/org/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull.java) have a retention policy of `CLASS`, meaning they can't be accessed at run-time via reflection. So, you should have `requires static org.jetbrains.annotations;` in your module-info descriptor, as you don't need or want those annotations at run-time.

Comment: @Slaw Okay, the clarifications was really helpful !
Now I  confirm that I can use the annotation !
Really thank you

Can you just re-write this in the answer section, so I can mark the question as solved ? 
(Or do you prefere that I write it myself ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not related to using non-modular dependencies in a modular context. As you've discovered, the dependency in question **is** modular; it has a `module-info` descriptor. And the name of this module is `org.jetbrains.annotations`.

The problem is that the dependency is a *compile-time only* dependency. You've explicitly marked it as such by using `<scope>compile</scope>` in your POM file<sup>1</sup>. That means Maven will place the dependency on the module-path at *compile-time* but **not** at *run-time*. This leads to an error because you have:

```java
requires org.jetbrians.annotations;
```

That tells the *Java Platform Module System* that the `org.jetbrains.annotations` module is required by the `DVDIndexer` module at **both** compile-time **and** run-time. To solve this problem, you need to have the following directive instead:

```java
requires static org.jetbrains.annotations;
```

The `static` keyword in this context means the required module is optional at run-time (but still required at compile-time). The main purpose of this feature is to allow a module to require another module at compile-time without forcing said other module to be present at run-time. In other words, it allows for compile-time only dependencies.

---

<sup>1. This is a good thing. The [java-annotations](https://github.com/JetBrains/java-annotations) library is designed to be a compile-time only dependency. Its purpose is to provide better documentation and possibly allow code analyzers to better analyze code for potential errors. But the library itself defines no run-time behavior, and the annotations all have a retention policy of `CLASS` (meaning they are not visible via reflection). Thus, there's no reason to require the dependency at run-time.</sup>

Comment: Really thank you for the explication (in commentary section too) !
Have a great day !